# Generate random variable with specific probabilities

Tags: stata

How can I generate a random variable in Stata with pre-defined probabilities for different categories?

For example, I want the variable to have four categories (`0`, `10`, `20`, `30`), all with `25%` probability.

Answer (score 1):

Random variables like these can also be drawn using the `mata` function `rdiscrete()`:

```
clear 
set obs 1000 

generate wanted = . 
mata: st_store(., "wanted", 10*rdiscrete(1000, 1, (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)):-10)

tabulate wanted


     wanted |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |        266       26.60       26.60
         10 |        235       23.50       50.10
         20 |        242       24.20       74.30
         30 |        257       25.70      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,000      100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want multiples of a uniform distribution on successive integers.

Although specific functions can be found, the general trick of rounding up or down and then multiplying can be used in conjunction with firing up `runiform()`:

```
clear 
set obs 1000 
set seed 4852 

generate wanted = 10 * floor(4 * runiform())

tabulate wanted

     wanted |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |        237       23.70       23.70
         10 |        245       24.50       48.20
         20 |        270       27.00       75.20
         30 |        248       24.80      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,000      100.00
```

See also:

- [the discussion of floor and ceiling functions](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0002)
- [this discussion of your problem](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0032)
- [the help on random number functions](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?random-number%20functions)